# What is the better way of writing input[type=text] or input[type="text"] in css

Tags: css, coding-style, standards

Writing some CSS for my own project. When writing styles for the form element, I wrote some CSS as below:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {}
```

Now I am confused what is the best way of writing this CSS. Is it the best way or should I write as:

```
input[type=text], input[type=email] {}
```

I mean with the double quotes or without any quote in the third brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best way use:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {}
```

**Reference:**

See here for more information:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: this url has nice description: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors